# function calling giving an, "Cannot read property 'length' of undefined"- AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-scope, typeerror

I am calling callKeywords like,

```
<input type="text" ng-change="keywordsList()" ng-model="searchkeyword.keystring" class="typeahead">
```

but its causing an error in jquery file.

My function inside controller:

```
$scope.callKeywords = function() {
    $http.get(myurl).then(calbacksuccess1,calbackerror1);
    function calbacksuccess1(response)
    {
        alert(response);
    }
    function calbackerror1(failure)
    {
        alert(failure);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are the alerts getting called after you call the service?

Answer (score -1):

I think the success and error callback functions should be attached to $scope variable. So try doing below :

```
$scope.callKeywords = function() {
    $http.get(myurl).then(calbacksuccess1,calbackerror1);
};
$scope.calbacksuccess1 = function(response){
    alert(response);
};
$scope.calbackerror1= function(failure){
    alert(failure);
};
```

This might be the issue.

Or

Another thing to check is if "searchkeyword" is not undefined. Check if $scope.searchkeyword = ""; is defined in scope.